# How to host a webserver and a database server on same Azure VM

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

How can we start 2 servers on a single VM in azure . I am having a standard D1 VM . I would like to host an app server along with a database server on my VM which run on different Port numbers .

I can do this locally by opening 2 terminals , but I dont see a way to do the same on cloud. I am new to cloud computing . Please help.

Comment: You can open up two ports on the VM - one for your app server and other for your database server. Will that work for you?

Comment: Do you mean increasing adding inbound port rules?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: But how do I host my 2 servers on these ports. I am able to host my web server via the terminal .. but i need another terminal to start my second server , isnt it?

Comment: I am not what you mean by terminal? Please edit your question and describe in detail how you're running these two servers on your local machine.

Comment: @PiyushKumar Your question is very vague and difficult to suggest any solution. Be more specific but elaborate

Comment: How you run software on a VM is really up to you. Just like a regular server, you can configure it any way you want. And how you set up your apps will be dependent on the OS you choose (Linux vs Windows). You're also talking about running software via a terminal, which is not going to work for unattended (headless) execution of code, since everything relies on you to run your software. Your question really is less of a cloud computing thing and more of a software install thing.

Comment: Note that the various cloud platforms have many services available to you, where you can run your various apps and services without a VM (there are web services, app services, database services...). These might be something you want to consider as well. All of these services are documented fairly thoroughly with lots of getting-started guides. I'd suggest starting there.

Answer (score 0):

When you install or configure or run your software on Azure VM, you can manage to do it just like a regular server after you SSH or RDP to that Azure VM.

First, you need to select the OS (Linux or Windows) of Azure VM for your software. After the Azure VM is provisioned successfully with [appropriated ports open in the network security group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal), you can access that Azure VM locally via RDP or SSH.

Then, you can install your web and database server on the Azure VM as usual on your local machine.

Here are some articles for your reference:

- [Tutorial: Install a LAMP web server on a Linux virtual machine in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-lamp-stack)
- [How to install SQL Server on azure vm](https://sqlstudies.com/2018/01/29/how-to-install-sql-server-on-an-azure-vm/)

Alternatively, you can install those servers automatically using the custom script extension with the [Set-AzVMExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/set-azvmextension?view=azps-3.6.1) cmdlet on the Azure Cloud Shell. The Azure Cloud Shell is an interactive, authenticated, browser-accessible shell for managing Azure resources. You could get more details from the tutorial: [Install the SQL, IIS, .NET stack in a Windows VM with Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-iis-sql)